# Overwrite index operation

Tags: c++

I know that it's possible to overwritew index operation [] in C++ 
and work with class internal data like with an array. 
Is it possible to overwrite [][] and to work like with two demension array ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible (and std::vector is an example of such a class).

You should overload operator[] in your class or structure.

In case you use positive integers to index data possible signature will be:

```
RETURN_TYPE operator[] (size_type n);
```

UPD: if you want two-dimensional data structure with non-negative integers as keys you can use vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<YOUR_TYPE>> vector_name;
```

Comment: Do you have an example how to do it. But std::vector is not two dimension

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve it you need to overload `operator[]` to return some object that have `operator[]` too. For example:

```
class Proxy {
     std::vector<int>::iterator it;
     //constructor;
     int operator[] (size_t pos) {
         return *(it + pos);
     }
}

class MyMatrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
    Proxy operator[] (size_t pos) {
        return Proxy(v[pos].begin());
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that if you're not doing bounds checking, and you use a single dimension implementation, a pointer is an adequate `Proxy`: `int* operator[]( int i ) { return &v[ i * columns ]; }`.  Similarly, if with your implementation, `std::vector<int>&` is a suitable proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you can; conventionally, you would overload [] return a reference to a row-type object, and overload [] on that row-type object to yield a reference to the scalar.

You should also consider overloading pointer dereference as well in order to maintain the equivalence of `[x]` and `*(... + x)`.

Comment: Your second suggestion really depends on the kind of the class in question. I can't really imagine `std::vector<int> v(100); *(v + 7) = 5;` being legal code.

Comment: @Angew; indeed. Hence the need to consider. If you were writing a matrix class then I think you should.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array `arr` whenever you want to acess `arr[x][y]` for exemple it has an equivalence of `(arr[x])[y]` so first of all `arr[x]` is evaluated (let's name it `a`) and then `a[y]` is evaluated so you have to overload just `[]`operator.

Comment: But (arr[x]) - must return a one dimension array, and a[y] - a value, how overload one operator for two different return types ?

Comment: @user1913557 array? Nop. It returns a pointer. Your left hand side of the `[]` operator is always a pointer.